# Spring security for multi tenants

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I've below properties in my properties file of auth server for oauth spring security to generate jwt token.

```
clientcredential:
  clients:
    - tenant: tenant1
      clientdetails:
        - name : service1
          scope : service1.read
          clientId: tenant1-service1-client
          clientSecret: tenant1-service1-secret
        - name : service2
            scope : service2.read
            clientId: tenant1-service2-client
            clientSecret: tenant1-service2-secret
        - name : service3
            scope : service3.read
            clientId: tenant1-service3-client
            clientSecret: tenant1-service3-secret
        - name : service4
            scope : service4.read
            clientId: tenant1-service4-client
            clientSecret: tenant1-service4-secret
    - tenant: tenant2
      clientdetails:
        - name : service1
            scope : service1.read
            clientId: tenant2-service1-client
            clientSecret: tenant2-service1-secret
        - name : service2
            scope : service2.read
            clientId: tenant2-service2-client
            clientSecret: tenant2-service2-secret
        - name : service3
            scope : service3.read
            clientId: tenant2-service3-client
            clientSecret: tenant2-service3-secret
```

I would like to validate the jwt token such that the token of one tenant should not work with another tenant.
I have request endpoint as https://domain/api/v1/save/{tenant}
where tennant is passed in path variable for each request.
We don't have any UI or such configuration for user configuration it's just an spring boot REST API project.

We are using inmemory client registered repository to store client details.

Comment: If you login with any client you are logged in to your application. So the user could select the client on your app's login page. You don't need any URL with tenant. If want some URLs only for one tenant, you could use different roles or check user in your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that a `tenant` claim is put into the JWT access token. When you then validate the request, you can verify whether the `tenant` claim equals the `tenant` from the path parameter.

You can put any claims in your access token and then use them for proper authorization decisions.